# What should I put in the 'savings' field on a UK visa application?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

Kindly clarify, on the UK visa application form where it is asked do you have savings? Would it be correct to state the closing balance on my bank statement?

Comment: "closing balance"? I would think this might raise more questions if you need to provide evidence - where is the money now?

Comment: @w3d I had bank statements that had "opening balance, credits, debits, closing balance" on every single bank statement. As in "close of month", not close of account.

Comment: @MarkHenderson Ah OK, thanks for that. I've only ever seen "closing balance" used when an account was actually closed (UK).

Answer (score 9):

We cannot tell you exactly where the question about savings is on the form. It's because the online forms are changing and currently in a 'beta' state. They are stable and collect the same information, but the end user experience is evolving and will continue to evolve until the whole system is migrated.  So the answer to your first question is indeterminate.

Having said that, you will eventually encounter a question like...

> Do you have savings, property or other income (for example from stocks
>   and shares)?  If ‘Yes’ please provide full details

They are not asking for a balance here. Instead they want to know the account details like which bank, their address, and type of account.  The place to show them the balance is in your evidence submission where you include bank statements.  Moreover, they are not concerned so much about the final balance. They want to see how the flows through the account map in to your personal circumstances and lifestyle.  And for savings accounts in particular they will be **especially concerned** about the provenance of the funds.  We have lots of refusals here in our archives where people have stumbled over establishing provenance.

What this amalgamates to is they do not want people to liquidate their savings to come for a visit. Instead they are trying to find out who you are along with your personal circumstances, your apparent lifestyle, and how deeply you are rooted to the local economy.

Successful applicants will usually submit 3 to 6 months of statements for each account they list. And they will establish provenance with absolute diligence.

Comment: I wouldn't +1 for a long word when a shorter one will do, especially when many non-native speakers will be reading... (Although I would +1 the answer because it is thorough and helpful, which I did)

Comment: The phrasing in the OP is a bit unclear, and I don't think he's asking where to find the question about savings but rather about the meaning of the question.

Comment: @davidvc: They can right click, Google the term, and learn something. If we all pander to a lack of knowledge then nobody will ever accrue any more.